# $S$-Units notation and Dirichlet's unit theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I'm having a hard time understanding some notions of a paper I'm working on. Let $L/K$ be a finite normal extension of number fields and $S$ be a set of places of $K$ prime to $p$ where $p$ denotes an odd prime. The author defines a group

$$R_{K,S} = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \otimes E_K, x \equiv 1 \mod \nu, \nu \in S\}$$
where $E_K$ denotes the groups of units of $K$.
Several questions arise:

1) Is $R_{K,S}$ equal the groups of $S$-units of $K$, $\mathcal{O}_{K,S}^\times = \{a\in K, v_{\mathfrak{p}}(a) = 0 \  \forall \mathfrak{p} \notin S \}$ as defined on page 451 of Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg: Cohomology of Number Fields, tensored with $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

2) What "happens" when tensoring over $\mathbb{Z}_p$? I know that you can make any group into a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module but is there any intuition why one would do that? Does the above group arise naturally as a kernel of some map?

3) Is there a more natural notion of the above group in terms of ideles?

4) A general question on Dirichlet's unit theorem for $S$-units: Is there a version without any constraints on $S$, i.e. without having to assume that the archimedian places are in $S$, i.e. $S_\infty \subset S$?

**EDIT**: Is $x \equiv 1 \mod \nu$ for $\nu \in S$ just an untypical notion of $S$ being a modulus $S = \prod_{\nu} \nu$?

Thank you for your help! :) Tom

**EDIT (11/29/2013)**:
For 1): My guess (above) is not right, but: Is $R_{K,S} = E_{K,S,1} \otimes \Bbb Z_p$, where $E_{K,S,1}$ denote the subgroup of $E_K$ that are principal units at every place $\nu \in S$?

For 2): I know now that tensoring over $\Bbb Z_p$ kills the prime-to-$p$-part and every module becomes a $\Bbb Z_p$-module, one can therefore speak of the $\Bbb Z_p$-rank of every module.

For 4): I now know that there can't be any version without the infinite places, because they are essential to the proof. But how can I actually use the Dirichlet unit theorem as stated in Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg: *Cohomology of Number Fields 2nd edition 2008*, proposition (8.7.2) to compute the $\Bbb Z_p$-rank of a $\Bbb Z_p$-submodule of $\mathcal{O}_{K,S}^\times$ of finite index?

Comment: Dear Tom: After your edits, I am no longer sure what you would like answered. Would you mind pointing it out exactly?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal My main problem is to understand $R_{K,S}$ and the congruence notation above. $R_{K,S}$ seems to be a submodule of the units $\mathcal{O}_{K,S}^\times$ tensored with $\Bbb Z_p$ of $K$ and via Dirichlet unit theorem it is isomorphic or injects into something that I don't know. How would one write down $R_{K,S}$ as an idèle?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Do you have an idea or a hint or a reference for me? That would help me very much and in addition the bounty won't get lost ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me give this a shot. First of all, I don't think the proposed definition of $R_{K, S}$ makes sense. On $\mathbf Z_p \otimes E_K$, we lose the residue class maps away from $p$. It should rather be

$$R_{K, S} = \{x \in E_K : x \equiv 1 \mod \nu, \forall \nu\in S\} \otimes_{\mathbf Z} {\mathbf Z_p}.$$

---

It is not true that $R_{K, S} = \mathcal O_{K, S}^\times \otimes \mathbf Z_p$. The rank of $R_{K, S}$ is bounded by the rank of $E_K$, and in general the rank of $\mathcal O_{K, S}^\times$ is much larger.

---

Tensoring with $\mathbf Z_p$, as you say, has the effect of killing the $p$-torsion. As for the question of why one would want to do that, I cannot really tell without seeing the context. In any case, I do not see a natural definition of $R_{K, S}$ in terms of idèles. I'm also not sure whether it appears naturally as the kernel of some map. (Sorry for all of these disappointing answers!)

---

As for Dirichlet's Unit Theorem, one does not in general assume that $S$ contains the archimedean places. For instance, the classical unit theorem (which states the finite-generatedness of $\mathcal O^\times_K$) is the case $S=\emptyset$, according to me. However, perhaps some authors use different definitions and consider the classical unit theorem to be the case where $S$ consists of all of the archimedean places. It really depends on the definitions at hand, but the statements should be the same in the end.